# SQL query that shows overlapping rows within a single table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been searching in Google and SO for an answer to this but having a hard time. Not even sure if I am asking it correctly, but I am going to give it my best shot here:

My data:

```
Fruit  | Attributes
-------------------
Apple  | Dark Red
Apple  | Green
Apple  | Yellow
Apple  | Light Red
Apple  | Greenish Yellow
Apple  | Dark Yellow
Apple  | Brown
Banana | Yellow
Banana | Greenish Yellow
Banana | Dark Yellow 
Banana | Yellow 
Banana | Brown
Banana | Red
Banana | Black
```

What I would like to do is run a query that outputs how many attributes for all fruits (in this case just apples and bananas) that overlap.

Hope I've been clear... please let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: You only want to compare two categories?

Comment: So you want the count of rows that have the same attributes but different fruit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ATTRIBUTE, FRUIT 
FROM FRUIT_TABLE
WHERE ATTRIBUTE IN (
    SELECT ATTRIBUTE
    FROM FRUIT_TABLE
    GROUP BY ATTRIBUTE
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FRUIT_NAME) > 1 )
ORDER BY ATTRIBUTE, FRUIT_NAME
```

I tried it with City and State in a similar way and it worked:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY, STATE 
FROM ADDRESS
WHERE CITY IN (
    SELECT CITY
    FROM ADDRESS
    GROUP BY CITY
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT STATE) > 1)
ORDER BY CITY, STATE
```

- BATH NB
- BATH ON
- BEDFORD  NS
- BEDFORD  QC
- BRANDON  MB
- BRANDON  MT
- Brampton NB
- Brampton ON

... and so on

```
SELECT ATTRIBUTE, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ATTRIBUTE, FRUIT 
    FROM FRUIT_TABLE
    WHERE ATTRIBUTE IN (
        SELECT ATTRIBUTE
        FROM FRUIT_TABLE
        GROUP BY ATTRIBUTE
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FRUIT_NAME) > 1 )
        ORDER BY ATTRIBUTE, FRUIT_NAME ) AS RESULTS
GROUP BY ATTRIBUTE
```

Comment: Exactly like that. Thank you!

Comment: Im playing with this and having some trouble returning the actual occurrences of the overlaps. Outputting all data showing overlaps is working fine...any thoughts? Ideally would like to see the Fruit and the amount of occurrences as two columns in the output.

Comment: Just wrap the entire result set in a group by (see edits)  if you want Fruit, just change it to fruit instead of attribute